# Close PreferenceFragment after widget configuration complete

Tags: android, android-widget, android-preferences

I am using a PreferenceFragment to configure my widget when it is added to the home screen.  After the user has edited the preference to their likings, how can I close the preference fragment so the widget can then be added based on the settings?

I was thinking of using an "Add Widget" preference at the bottom of the fragment, and adding an onClickListener. But am at a loss as what to do programmatically after the user clicks this.  I was thinking something like a finish() method, but this only works on Activities.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [App Widgets guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring): You must create an `Intent`, add the app widget Id as an extra (with the `AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID` key), call setResult and finish. If it's a fragment, use `getActivity()` to call these methods on the Activity.

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result); // or getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish(); // or getActivity().finish();
```